# mongodb shell login - password contains special characters like -(hyphen) and '(single quote)

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, command-line, mongodb-shell

I am trying to login to mongodb database using mongodb shell, and if the password contains any special characters like -(hyphen) or '(single quote) , it gives error - `Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '-8B'df5='`.

```
mongo -u username -p -8B'df5= --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Kindly help

Comment: Try `mongo -u username -p "-8B'df5="`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The manual for the deprecated `mongo` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongo) makes it clear that the preferred way to pass a connection string is as a URI. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/ makes it clear that usernames and passwords can be passed as part of that URI.

```sh
mongo mongodb://username:-8B%27df5%3D@hostname/admin
```

`%27` is the URL-escaping version of `'`

`%3D` is the URL-escaping version of `=`

Python's `urllib.quote()` is one of the many ways you can look up these mappings yourself.

Comment: in Python3 use `urllib.parse.quote()` along with `import urllib.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with (the deprecated) mongo shell, instead it has something to do the way your operating system shell parsing the parameters.
You may choose to:

- keep using single quote, but you have to escape the single quote inside the string with backslash.
- use double quote to enclose the string

So you may use below command instead:

```
mongo -u username -p '-8B\'df5=' --authenticationDatabase admin
```

or

```
mongo -u username -p "-8B'df5=" --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Comment: An escape character in a singe-quote string may not work.  Singe-quote strings are read literally, so the escape is not parsed.  The double-quote version will work, but characters like $ etc need to be escaped